# Spring Integration kafka : org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException while running consumer

Tags: spring, spring-integration, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I tried to run Kafka consumer from the code it always exception but i ran kafka-console-consumer.sh file to check producer it works fine and show all message received by broker. Below are pom.xml code and exception logs. Kindly tell where i am wrong.

```
public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "192.168.56.101:2181");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group_id_coonfig" );
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "100");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "15000");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    return props;
}
```

Here is my Test class code.

```
@Test
public void testSpringKafkaConsumer() throws InterruptedException {

    try{
    String topics[] = { "programTopic3" };
    ConsumerFactory<Integer, String> factory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(configs);
    factory.createConsumer();
    AbstractMessageListenerContainer<Integer, String> container = new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(factory,
            topics);
    container.setBeanName("container");

    final BlockingQueue<ConsumerRecord<Integer, String>> records = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    container.setMessageListener(new MessageListener<Integer, String>() {

        @Override
        public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<Integer, String> message) {
            // logger.info("received: " + message);
            System.out.println("received: --------+++++++++++++++------------" + message);
            records.add(message);
        }
    });
    KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<Integer, String> adaptor = new KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<>(container);

    adaptor.start();
    ConsumerRecord<Integer, String> poll = null;
    while((poll =records.take()) != null){
        System.out.println(poll.topic() + "  topic");
        System.out.println(poll.key() + "   key");
        System.out.println(poll.value()+ "  value");
    }

    }catch(Exception exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        Assert.fail();
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.learn.kafka.integrate.spring</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringIntegrationKafka</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>SpringIntegrationKafka</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Integration kafka</description>

<properties>
    <springVersion>4.2.5.RELEASE</springVersion>
    <springIntegrationVersion>4.2.5.RELEASE</springIntegrationVersion>
    <mockitoVersion>1.10.19</mockitoVersion>
</properties>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repository.spring.milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springIntegrationVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
<version>0.9.0.1</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-test</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Exception log:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "value.deserializer" which has no default value.
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:148)
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:49)
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:56)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.<init>(ConsumerConfig.java:336)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:512)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:494)
at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:46)
at com.learn.kafka.integrate.spring.TestConsumer.testSpringKafkaConsumer(TestConsumer.java:83)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: You are not showing the whole story `ConsumerFactory<Integer, String> factory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(configs);` - it appears the `configs` variable does not reference the properties created by `consumerConfigs()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "value.deserializer" which has no default value.
```

Looks like your `new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(configs);` doesn't use that `consumerConfigs()`.

From other side the `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` does exactly this in its ctor:

```
this.messageListenerContainer = messageListenerContainer;
this.messageListenerContainer.setAutoStartup(false);
this.messageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(this.listener);
```

So, your `container.setMessageListener(new MessageListener<Integer, String>() {` isn't reachable. Therefore nothing is going to appear in the `records`.

I'd recommend avoid Spring Integration for this particular test if you don't understand it yet.

For the `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` variant you have to specify the `outputChannel` as a `QueueChannel` to retrieve message with the `poll` manner.

But also you have to do more `BeanFactory` stuff around `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`.

See our test-case for more info: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/kafka/inbound/MessageDrivenAdapterTests.java

Also pay attention to the sample application based on Kafka-0.9, too: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/kafka

Comment: Thanks for the valuable feedback. I tried the same code it working fine if I gave 9092 port number with address which is kafka server port but if run from kafka consumer console I provide zookeeper port 2181. So I am confused with this.

Comment: Yes, that's correct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935596/zookeeper-usage-on-kafka-0-9-0

Comment: I have error:- Missing required configuration "group.id" which has no default value.  How to solve this error?